# True/False datatype in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, sqldatatypes

Hi I would like to know what datatype allows me to use the values: true or false in my table.
I can choose BOOLEAN (or TINYINT) and use the values 1 and 0 but was just wondering about the values "true" and "false"

Answer (score 1):

> **9.1.6 Boolean Literals**
>
> The constants `TRUE` and `FALSE` evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively. The constant names can be written in any lettercase.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html

Comment: Note:  There are no quotes around `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean in MySql

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/THY7692)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyGuests;

CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    test boolean
);

INSERT INTO MyGuests (test)
    VALUES (true);

SELECT * FROM MyGuests;
```

Comment: it is showing me this error when applying BOOLEAN datatype while having values of true or false:
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1366: Incorrect integer value: 'False' for column 'BoolCtrActv' at row 1
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `careers`.`ntn` 
CHANGE COLUMN `BoolCtrActv` `BoolCtrActv` TINYINT NOT NULL

Comment: What is your create table? Did you see my Sql Demo ?

Comment: @John - What was the datatype before the Alter?  Did you have the _string_ "False" in a _varchar_?